# Dynamically inserted input boxes won't POST

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post, dynamic

I have a form that I generate new input fields to with javascript and the generated fields won't post.
I have made a demo which I stripped the database etc. because it might not have been secure (for injections) which var_dumps POST

http://resk.latvalashop.com/test.php

Try to fill in everything and press a couple times the "+" button to add a couple of rows, fill them and then press "Tallenna" which will POST the form.

the problem is the floating element to right of the main element, the first fields are not generated by javascript and POST as they should, but if you press the "+" and try to post from the newly created forms nothing will be POSTed.

Any help appriciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Breaking a HTML form into several <form>s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732600/breaking-a-html-form-into-several-forms)

Comment: To Dr. Molle: Kindof, but I am asking different things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated input elemnts are not contained inside of an `<form>` element, so they are not able to be posted. You should push your `<form action="result.php" ... >` higher up in the DOM hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your HTML.

The level where you open your `<form>` element (3 `<div>`'s deep) isn't the same as where you close it (2 `<div>`'s deep). That will probably fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap those with `<form></form>`  tags.